# Which binary file format would be suitable to store a dictionary of numeric arrays?

Tags: json, dictionary, binary, language-agnostic, file-format

I have a set of JSON files containing dictionaries of numeric arrays. Array type can be integer, unsigned integer, float and boolean.

Here is a sample (of course typical file is way larger, with more keys and longer arrays):

```
{
    "distance": [0, 20, 80, 200],
    "time": [0.3, 0.468, 0.976, 1.234],
    "active": [true, true, false, true]
}
```

The dictionary keys come from a fixed set of possible keys, but not every key is present in every file (for example, some of the files would not contain the "active" key/value pair).

My goal is to store in binary to decrease file size and increase reading speed.

I thought about using TIFF, due to its tag/length/value architecture, but for what I have seen, a proper compliant TIFF would be an overkill I think. So I wonder if there is another well-known tag/length/value format, or a different suitable binary format, or what I should take into consideration if I am to design my own, personal format oriented to this specific data-set.

Answer (score 1):

For these types of data, there are several popular binary formats. I'd say the top 2 are: [asn.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and [protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).

ASN.1 has the advantage of being an ISO/IEC and ITU standard. That is, it's a "proper" standard. It's what cellphones and cell towers use to encode metadata. It's old which means that it's been battle-tested. The disadvantage of asn.1 is that it's a very complex standard. It has 3 different formats for binary encoding (of course, your implementation may choose to implement just one format). The full standard is covered in 12 standards documents (even if you choose to just implement one binary format, that requires you to read at least four documents).

Protobuf is what Google use internally to talk between servers in order to reduce bandwidth compared to JSON or XML. It's also very fast compared to asn.1. The only disadvantage is that it's not a "proper" standard with standards documents. So documentation may be lacking.

Now for the good news. Since both the above protocols are popular, there are a lot of libraries out there in almost any language you're using that implement them. So you don't really need to read the documentation in-depth.

It's tempting to just opt for speed and go for protobuf but personally I prefer to quickly try both and see which has a library with an API that I like. After all, I'll be spending time coding and presumably debugging in it.

---

#### Additional answer:

There's also [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) which is a binary format inspired by JSON and I believe is directly interoperable with JSON.

There's a nice wikipedia page that compares various encoding formats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted. I found it by pure luck (while looking for Pyton Pandas DataFrame serialization), but it seems amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) protocol by pure luck, but was very impressed with it!

JSON 137 bytes

```
{
    "distance": [0, 20, 80, 200],
    "time": [0.3, 0.468, 0.976, 1.234],
    "active": [true, true, false, true]
}
```

MessagePack (hex) 70 bytes 51 %

```
83 a8 64 69 73 74 61 6e 63 65 94 00 14 50 cc
c8 a4 74 69 6d 65 94 cb 3f d3 33 33 33 33 33
33 cb 3f dd f3 b6 45 a1 ca c1 cb 3f ef 3b 64
5a 1c ac 08 cb 3f f3 be 76 c8 b4 39 58 a6 61
63 74 69 76 65 94 c3 c3 c2 c3
```

Even though I got better results by plain ZIP compression, this might be much faster to read than ZIP files. Anyway it's a possibility.